# bash - surround all array elements or arguments with quotes

Tags: linux, bash

I want to write a function in bash that forwards arguments to `cp` command.
For example:
for the input

```
<function> "path/with whitespace/file1" "path/with whitespace/file2" "target path"
```

I want it to actually do:

```
cp "path/with whitespace/file1" "path/with whitespace/file2" "target path"
```

But instead, right now I'm achieving:

```
cp path/with whitespace/file1 path/with whitespace/file2 target path
```

The method I tried to use is to store all the arguments in an array, and then just run the cp command together with the array.
Like this:

```
function func {
    argumentsArray=( "$@" )
    cp ${argumentsArray[@]}
}
```

unfortunately, It doesn't transfer the quotes like I already mentioned, and therefore the copy fails.

Comment: See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like `$@`, you need to quote the array expansion.

```
func () {
    argumentsArray=( "$@" )
    cp "${argumentsArray[@]}"
}
```

However, the array serves no purpose here; you can use `$@` directly:

```
func () {
    cp "$@"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works when doing `func "the file.txt" /tmp`, however it shows an error when trying to use `func "*.txt" /tmp`. The reason is understood ("shell expansion", etc.), but... does a solution exist?

Comment: Not a good one. I recommend writing `func` to you can call it as `func /tmp *.txt`, so that you can use `shift` to remove `/tmp` from the list of positional arguments and use `"$@"` to access the remaining arguments (which came from `*.txt`).