# Trouble Calling Program with Arguments Inside Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell, whitespace, quotes

**Problem**

I have code that first iterates through a file with a folder path per line ensuring they are correct (which it does pass, and I also know these to be valid paths), and then tries to pass it to the program `borg` but errors.

The problem seems to be all down to how I'm creating or using `folderList` (which you can see as the first echo) but I'm not sure how to fix it.

**Input**

```
/media/sf_D_DRIVE/VirtualMachines Backups/
/media/sf_C_DRIVE/Websites/47/sln/site/App_Data/
```

**Error Output**

```
"/media/sf_D_DRIVE/VirtualMachines Backups/" "/media/sf_C_DRIVE/Websites/47/sln/site/App_Data/"

"/media/sf_D_DRIVE/VirtualMachines: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '"/media/sf_D_DRIVE/VirtualMachines'
Backups/": [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Backups/"'
"/media/sf_C_DRIVE/Websites/47/sln/site/App_Data/": [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '"/media/sf_C_DRIVE/Websites/47/sln/site/App_Data/"'
```

**Code**

```
#this snippet reads in folder paths from a file
while read line
do
    exists=false
    if [ -f "$line" ]; then
        exists=true
    fi
    if [ -d "$line" ]; then
        exists=true
    fi
    if [ $exists = false ]; then
        exit 1
    fi
    folderList+=" $line"
done < "$2"

echo $folderList #gets past here successfully

borg create -s --progress $1::${dateString} $folderList
```

Comment: Use an array to build multiple arguments with whitespaces: [bash - surround all array elements or arguments with quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35868710/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that should work better by using an array to pass arguments and simplifying your condition testing:

```sh
while read -r line
do
    if [ -f "$line" ] || [ -d "$line" ]; then
      folderList+=( "$line" )
    else
      exit 1
    fi
done < "$2"

echo "${folderList[@]}" #gets past here successfully

borg create -s --progress "$1::${dateString}" "${folderList[@]}"
```